# Strategy to Cache MySQL tables

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis

If you have an user table related to address table as many to many relationship, then what's the best strategy to cache it for Performance?

Comment: write specific interface to get all data from mysql and cache them to redis. call this interface before your projects online.

Comment: I have tables as A <--many to many--> with B,C and A<--one to many ---->D,E,F. Is it wise to cache so much data under one userId ?